# Regex search matching an element-ID, or element-Name/Value

Tags: javascript, browser, dom

I want to create a script (JavaScript) to enumerate through all "radio" elements searching for those that have an "ID" (or perhaps "Name" and "Value") that matches some regexs. If there is a match, I'll execute additional code depending on which regex matched. Searching by "ID" should be easier than searching by "Name" and "Value", but in some cases the elements don't have an "ID", so in those cases, I'd search for a regex match by "Name" and "Value".

Here are some typical sets of "radio" elements:

```
<span>
<input id="ABC123" onclick="somefunction('DEF');" name="GHI" value="JKL45" type="radio">
<input id="MNO678" onclick="somefunction('PQR');" name="GHI" value="STU90" type="radio">
</span>

<span>
<input name="GHI" value="JKL45" type="radio">
<input name="GHI" value="STU90" type="radio">
</span>
```

I have most of the JavaScript worked out below. This script will be saved as the "URL" of a web-browser shortcut (bookmark/favorite). This is generally referred to as a "Bookmarklet" (or "Favlet" for IE).

Here's what I have so far:

```
javascript: 
(function(){ 
  function dorado(rado){ 
    /* 
    Here I want to test if the value of the "ID" for 
    the element "rado" matches any 1 of 2-or-3 different 
    regex's. If there is no "ID" then I'd test "Name" and "Value" 

    If none of the regex's match, I'll return. 
    Otherwise, I'll execute additional code depending on which regex matched. 
    */ 
  } 
  var x,k,f,j; 
  x=document.forms; 
  for (k=0; k<x.length; ++k) { 
    f=x[k]; 
    for (j=0;j<f.length;++j) 
// call dorado() only for "radio" elements. 
      if (f[j].type.toLowerCase() == "radio") 
        dorado(f[j]); 
  } 
} 
)();
```

---

**Edited:** 9/11/2013 5:48 PM (CT), additional details provided.

A little clarification... "radio-id" attribute should uniquely identify each `"<input"` element on the page of type "radio". In some cases, an `"<input"` element may not have its "ID" attribute set. In those cases, I have to inspect "radio-name" and "radio-value", together, because "radio-name" will not uniquely identify each radio element in cases where radio buttons are grouped together for selection as "1 of many" ("radio-name" will usually be the same for all grouped radio elements), and "radio-value" may be the same for many radio elements on the page.

So, as I am inspecting each "radio" element (in a loop), I first need to determine if the "radio-id" attribute is set.

If the "radio-id" attribute is set, I'll need to test if the "ID" matches any 1 of 2-or-3 different regex expressions. If nothing matches, I'll just "return". Otherwise, I'll execute additional code depending on which regex matched.

Likewise, if the "radio-id" attribute is NOT set, I'll need to test if the "name" and "value" matches any 1 of 2-or-3 different regex expressions. If nothing matches, I'll just "return". Otherwise, I'll execute additional code depending on which regex matched. For the purpose of the regex, the "name" and "value" could be tested together by combining them something like this:

```
radioName =  /* name attribute of element */;  
radioValue = /* value attribute of element */;  
teststr = radioName . ":" . radioValue;
```

It would probably be easiest to pre-define the regex expression strings like:

```
var IDregexlist=new Array("/test1/","/test2/","/test3/"); /* example: "/ABC[0-9]+/", "/MNO[0-9]+/" ... */  
var NVregexlist=new Array("/test4/","/test5/","/test6/"); /* example: "/GHI:JKL[0-9]+/", "/GHI:STU[0-9]+/" ... */
```

then in the dorado function, test for regex match of each item in the arrays like:

```
for each (rexpr in IDregexlist) {... };
```

I shouldn't have a problem with the bulk of the JavaScript code, except I need to know, within the function dorado(rado){ ... }:

1. How to get the "ID, "name" and "value" of the element (would this just be "rado.id", "rado.name", and "rado.value"?)
2. how to do the regex match tests and how to tell if an expression matched.

Comment: Could you give an example of the regex you're trying to match?

Comment: @thgaskell - It would be something like a fixed string followed by an underscore followed by some numbers, so the regex search expression would be something like **`/ABC_[0-9]+/`**.

Answer (score 0):

```
//radio matches any 1 of 3 regexes
var regexes = {valueRegex: /test/, idRegex: /\d/, nameRegex: /\w/};

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var radios = Array.prototype.filter.call(inputs, function(input) {
    return input.type === 'radio';
});

radios.forEach(function(radio) {
    doRado(radio);
});

function doRado(radio) {
    var keys = Object.keys(regexes);
    for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i ++) {
        //which: if there's no ID, test name and value
        var which = radio.id || radio.name || radio.value;
        var match = which.match(regexes[keys[i]]);
        if(match) {
            //do something depending on which regex matched
            console.log(which + ' matched regex ' + keys[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cpu1/wFQvU/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide your answer. This is a little more advanced than I can wrap my newbie brain around. In the line: **`"radios.forEach(function(radio) {"`**, where does **`"function(radio)"`** come from. Also, in **`"function doRado(radio) {"`**, I assume **`"radio.id"`** returns the ID attribute of the radio element.

Comment: The entire statement `radios.forEach...` is similar to using a for loop. In each iteration `forEach` assigns the `radio` parameter to the current array element `(radios[0], radios[1],..., radios[i])`. Yes, radio.id, radio.name correspond to the radio button's attributes. The `radios` array contains all `<input type="radio"/>` elements, so `radio` in `function doRado()` refers to one of those elements. In fact, the entire iteration part is similar to yours, you can substitute your `dorado` with `doRado`

Comment: In line **`"radios.forEach(function(radio) {..."`**, your use of **`"function('object')"`** confuses me. Is **`"function('object')"`** just a "Template" to define the name of the (forEach) variable used in the function inside the "{}"? Could **`"radios.forEach(function(radio) {..."`** be rewritten as: **`"for each (radio in radios) {doRado(radio);}"`**?  (I also edited my question to provide additional details).